# Trying to convert a DEM to a PCRaster and save it as .map getting the error -The following layers were not correctly generated-

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, convert, pcraster

I use QGIS Version 3.28.2 but tested it also with Version 3.28.4

If I use the PCRaster tool "Convert to PCRaster Format" and save the file as temporary layer it works. But I can't save this temporary layer as GeoTIFF and if I use the "Save to file" possibility in the "Convert to PCRaster Format" I get an error message (The following layers were not correctly generated).

The "Raster layer" is a GeoTIFF with a pixel size of 25m; as "output data type" I use "Scalar"